# ExpressJS - Refactoring nested callbacks and handling errors in app.get functions?

Tags: node.js, express

I am quite new to Node.js and already frustrated due to nested callbacks which make it very hard to read the code and troubleshoot for typos.

As you can see below, I have 2 associated models (Blog and Comment) and app.get method which I create Comment for a Blog post.

```
Model Structure:
Blog
..title (string)
..blog (string)
..comments (Referenced Comment Model) 
....comment (string)

Comment
..comment(string)
```

Currently app.get method has 3 nested call back functions, possible errors are only console.logged yet (for a better user experience if I start to write more codes for errors function becomes real mess).

```
app.post('/blog/:id/comment',function(req,res){
  Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, newComment){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
          if (err){
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            foundBlog.comments.push(newComment);
            foundBlog.save(function(err, data){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/blog/'+req.params.id);
                }
            });
          }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Here I would like to ask your suggestions to simplify below function and how to better handling errors.

Comment: Learn to love [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  One of their main purposes is to help refactor you out of [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: Use `promises` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, promises is the way to go and async/await is generally the most elegant approach to writing promises. As an example, your code could be condensed to the below. You should read up on promises as they are an important concept for node development.

```
app.post('/blog/:id/comment', async function(req,res){
  try{
   const newComment = await Comment.create(req.body.comment);
   const foundBlog = await Blog.findById(req.params.id);

   foundBlog.comments.push(newComment);
   await foundBlog.save();
   res.redirect('/blog/'+req.params.id);
  }
  catch(err){
   console.log(err);
  }      

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Mongoose, which supports promises, so you could do something like this:

```
app.post('/blog/:id/comment',(req,res) {
  Comment.create(req.body.comment)
    .then(newComment => {
      return Blog.findById(req.params.id))
        .then(foundBlog => {
          foundBlog.comments.push(newComment)
          return foundBlog.save()
        })
    })
    .then(() => res.redirect('/blog/' + req.params.id))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

You could also use **async-await**:

```
app.post('/blog/:id/comment', async (req, res) {
  try {
    const newComment = await Comment.create(req.body.comment)
    const foundBlog = await Blog.findById(req.params.id)
    foundBlog.comments.push(newComment)
    await foundBlog.save()
    res.redirect('/blog/' + req.params.id)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```